# C# - Probably ploblem with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Tags: c#, decimal, output

I have a problem with the output in the code below.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class GreaterNum
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double num1 = 0;
        double num2 = 0;

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        Console.Write("Enter first number: ");
        bool isDouble1 = Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num1);

        Console.Write("Enter second number: ");
        bool isDouble2 = Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num2);

        if (isDouble1 && isDouble2)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("The greater number is: " + Math.Max(num1, num2));
        }
        else
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number!");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the numbers are not with decimal "." the output is:

Enter first number: 1,2
Enter second number: 2,3
The greater number is: 23

Comment: That is to be expected. The ',' is a thousand separator so the parse will ignore it

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
    new CultureInfo("nl");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` as well.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```